# Troubleshooting my internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

While I was out of the house, my father rearranged the network cables a bit. I don't know what he has done exactly - He says nothing more then pulling and untangling.

When I came back home, my internet connection changed its IP from 192.168.0.205 to 169.254.197.233. The speed changed from 1Gbps to 10Mbps. It has also been at 100Mbps for a while. My subnetmask changed from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0. The standard gateway changed from 192.168.0.1 to no standard gateway. My DNS servers remain the same.

I have checked the lights of the UTP ports, and it looks like it's only sending a heartbeat every few seconds.

A sketch of the (relevant part of) the network:

```
My PC ----- extender ----- modem
        ^      ^       ^        
      Wired    |     Wired 
               |    
        This thing connects 
      two cables to each other
```

All the cabling is gigabit, my network card is a `Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111(P) Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)`. THe modem is a `CBN SVG6540E`

I have no idea what is going on here and I don't know how to find out either. Any help is welcome! If you need any more info, please ask.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the network equipment you have. Do you have a cable modem, switch, router? It sounds like your father disconnected a Gigabit-router and plugged the computer directly into the wall-jack or modem.

Answer (score 3):

The 169.254.x.x is the automatic private ip address Windows gives you when your connection to the dhcp source is gone, for example, the connection to your router.  Take a look at all of the cables and see that everything is still connected firmly.  Connect directly to the router and see if your internet access returns.  Work your way back from the modem to the router (assuming you have one) to your pc(s).

Comment: Yeah, check the cables on the router. The WAN port is for the internet connection and the LAN ports are for the computers on your home network.

Comment: Well, I still don't know what was wrong, but after taking the cables apart and plugging them back in, it is working now.

Comment: Excellent, it might have just been the dreaded "loose cable".